# How to download xlsx file with curl php?

Tags: php, curl

The xls file:

```
$accept = fopen("c:\\accept.xls", "wb");
```

Then:

```
CURLOPT_FILE   => $accept,
```

and no problem

---

For xlsx file:

With PHPExcel create accept.xlsx :

```
 include "C:\...\Classes\PHPExcel.php";
 include "C:\...\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007.php";
 include "C:\...\Classes\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php";

 $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
 $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("my_company");
 $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setLastModifiedBy("my_company");
 $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Document");
 $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Document");
 $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setDescription("Document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP     classes.");

                          $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
                          $objWriter->save("c:\\accept.xlsx");
```

File is created.
 But how to pass on CURLOPT_FILE ?

```
$accept = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("C:\\accept.xlsx");         // It is not correct.
```

---

Create file xlsx with PHPExcel. Then

```
    $accept = fopen("C:\\accept.xlsx", "wb");    // w+ --> such result                                                                                                      

    See in file system (Vista):                                                                                                     
    at first            accept              13:44       10kb                                                                
    then                accept              13:45       0kb                                                             
    then                accept              13:48       292kb       but Don't open                                              



    $accept = fopen("C:\\accept.xlsx", "rb");    //                                                                                                     

    See in file system:                                                                                                     
    at first            accept                          10kb                                                                
    then                                                                                                        

    Warning: curl_setopt_array(): the provided file handle is not writable in                                                                                                       
    … on line 83                        [ curl_setopt_array($ch, $options); ]                                                                               
     cURL Error: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate                                                                                                        



    $accept = fopen("C:\\accept.xlsx", "r+");    //                                                                                                         

    See in file system:                                                                                                     
    at first            accept                          10kb                                                                
    then                accept                          292kb       but Don't open
```

---

So file opens, but when it is created : 10kb.
Then don't open.

---

```
<?php

$b = strrev(mb_substr(sha1(mt_rand() . microtime()),5,16));//
$boundary = "----WebKitFormBoundary". substr_replace($b, mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($b, 7, 5)), 7, 5); 

$headers30 = array
(
    "Host: www.sss.qqq.ua",
    "Connection: keep-alive",
    "Cashe-Control: max-age=0",
    "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Origin: https://www.sss.qqq.ua",
    "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36",
    "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=".$boundary,
    "Referer: https://www.sss.qqq.ua/shop/price",    
    "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch",
    "Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4",
   "Expect:"
);
$data = array
(
    'tp'            =>'xls',
    'tr'            =>'34',
    'ct'            =>'0',
    'dm'            =>'0',
    'cd'            =>'save'
);
function multipart_build_query($fields, $boundary){
  $retval = '';
  foreach($fields as $key => $value){
    $retval .= "--$boundary\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"$key\"\r\n\r\n$value\r\n";
  }

  $retval .= "--$boundary--\r\n";
  return $retval;
}
$body = multipart_build_query($data, $boundary);
//
$options30 = array(
CURLOPT_URL             => 'https://www.sss.qqq.ua/shop/price',
CURLOPT_HEADER          => TRUE,       //
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => FALSE,      // 
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => TRUE,       // 
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS       => 7,          //
CURLOPT_ENCODING        => '',         //
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT  => 60,         //
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 80,         //
CURLOPT_VERBOSE         => TRUE,       //
CURLOPT_STDERR          => $log30,     //
CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER     => $hd30,      //
CURLOPT_FILE            => $send30,    //
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => TRUE,       //
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => 2,          //
CURLOPT_CAINFO          => 'C:/Certificates/mycertspem/manycerts.pem',//
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => $headers30, // 
CURLOPT_COOKIE          => $ssl,       //
CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE      => $cookfile,  //
CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR       => $cookfile,  //
CURLOPT_POST            => TRUE,       //
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => $body       //
);
//------------------------------------------------<
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options30);
$output_30 = curl_exec($ch);
      if ($output_30 === FALSE) {
       echo "cURL Error: " . curl_error($ch);
      }
$info30 = curl_getinfo($ch);
//sleep(1); // my exp...
curl_close($ch);
fclose($log30);
fclose($hd30);
fclose($send30);//
//------------------------------------------------>
//
?>
```

Comment: Why not `fopen()` the file too to get a filepointer? It doesn't really matter what's inside the file. Think of a byte chain as a file. If it's a valid Excel 2003, 2007, PDF or whatever byte chain. It's still just a byte chain which has to be transfered. The format of the file doesn't matter.

Comment: When the file xlsx is already created:
$accept = fopen("c:\\accept.xlsx", "wb");
CURLOPT_FILE   => $accept, ---> I receive an error curlopt_httpheader.

Comment: call `var_dump($accept)` and tell us the value.

Comment: Thanks, TiMESPLiNTER. Thanks for your participation. Has probably specified a problem above. With httpheader - my discrepancy.

Comment: In the first case (wb and w +) fopen () recreates a file. But it exists. I so have understood.
The second and third case I can not understand.

Comment: Show us your CURL code please.

Comment: It large. How much correctly to place it here? Log looked - ok.

Comment: Edit your start post and add the curl code section of your PHP file.

Comment: ok : $accept == $send30.

Comment: Change `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => TRUE` to `false`.

Comment: Did earlier - does not work - https does not start up.

Comment: With FALSE and "rb" in fopen() : Warning: curl_setopt_array(): the provided file handle is not writable in ... (above)

Comment: Comment out this lines `CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER     => $hd30,` and `CURLOPT_STDERR          => $log30,     //`

Comment: $log30 : * About to connect() to www.sss.qqq.ua port 443 (#29)
*   Trying xxx.yy.zz.ss…
* Connected to www.sss.qqq.ua (xxx.yy.zz.ss...) port 443 (#29)
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 29

Comment: It is when false and rb. When 292kb : hd30 and log30 ok.

Comment: without curl : create phpexcel xlsx file - opend ok // if then make fopen() - don/t open.